# Maven Project in Jenkins - No files in repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I am having a maven Java project in my local workspace, I am integrating it with jenkins. In the jenkins I created a Maven Project and in configuration I am giving pom.xml from my local workspace.
Build seems to be success but when I open the workspace in jenkins it says no files, also I am triggering an email which has an attachment from the workspace.
Email gets sent without the attachment.

[Screenshots on configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS2aa.png)

Following are the components I am using

> Jenkins 1.600
>
> apache-maven 3.3.3
>
> Maven Integration plugin 2.7.1 inside jenkins

Comment: Could you please share the configuration of your Jenkins project. The log output from the job would be helpful as well.

Comment: What kind of Jenkins Project you are created , is it a Free Style , Maven Jenkins , Pipeline ?

Comment: Its a Maven Project

Comment: @tom1299 I have attached screenshots of configuration

Comment: The screenshot does not reveal anything unusual. The log of the Job that failed would be really helpful.

Comment: Issue was with the root directory setting, it works fine now. Thanks